# Solution making a "small" generator, that when you click on a button called generate, it outputs an image and some text

Tags: generator

so I wanna make a generator that, when you click a big orange button (a rectangle with some fat text in it), you go to a new webpage, where some text is displayed and an image (or just the image alone). But of course this needs to be random everytime, so you do not just get the same image / text everytime. Is there an "easy" solution? Or at least a decent solution to this?

Its for a school project so as much help as possible would be awesome!

Comment: What have you tried so far? This question is very broad and it will be difficult to point you in the right direction without some clarification.

Comment: I have no clue where to start that is the main issue. I have tried to make a button so once you push it, it will generate an image. But that did not seem to work at all.....

Comment: I thought of using the switch statement and just use cases from 1-4 (since I'm using a math.random*4 +1 so I get a nuber between 1-4

Comment: Can you share more info on what technologies you're using? Java? HTML?

Comment: Java and HTML with some css for styling :)

Comment: I recommend editing this question or posting a new question with more details and being a lot more specific about what you're having a problem with or where you're getting stuck. Also please show what you've tried so far and what error(s) if any you're getting. Right now to most people this question sounds like a "please do my homework" problem, which is probably why it isn't getting much response.